# How to display D3.js charts in Apple Watch?

Tags: javascript, swift, d3.js, watchos

In their fitness monitoring app in **Apple Watch** they are displaying activity charts in the form of colorful concentric circles.

Is there a way to display my D3.js charts on **Apple Watch**?

Comment: Interesting question. Can iWatch display HTML + JS?

Comment: I don't think so. You would need an `WKWebView` which is not supported on watchOS

Answer (score 1):

You might find this helpful I guess. [Apple Watch Activity](https://codepen.io/xna2/pen/Dmqso)

HTML

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bm-w/d3/master/d3.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
html{
   height: 100%;
}
body {
   min-height: 100%;
   background: #000000;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
.icon{
   font-family:fontawesome;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:30px;
}
.goal,.completed{
   font-family: 'Roboto','Myriad Set Pro', 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
   fill:white;
   text-anchor:middle;
}
.goal{
   font-size: 30px;
}
.completed{
   font-size: 95px;
}
```

JS

```
    //based on https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1096355
//apple design:https://images.apple.com/watch/features/images/fitness_large.jpg
"use strict";

(function(){
    var gap = 2;

    var ranDataset = function () {
        var ran = Math.random();

        return    [
            {index: 0, name: 'move', icon: "\uF105", percentage: ran * 60 + 30},
            {index: 1, name: 'exercise', icon: "\uF101", percentage: ran * 60 + 30},
            {index: 2, name: 'stand', icon: "\uF106", percentage: ran * 60 + 30}
        ];

    };

    var ranDataset2 = function () {
        var ran = Math.random();

        return    [
            {index: 0, name: 'move', icon: "\uF105", percentage: ran * 60 + 30}
        ];

    };
    var colors = ["#e90b3a", "#a0ff03", "#1ad5de"];
    var width = 500,
            height = 500,
            τ = 2 * Math.PI;

    function build(dataset,singleArcView){

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .startAngle(0)
                .endAngle(function (d) {
                    return d.percentage / 100 * τ;
                })
                .innerRadius(function (d) {
                    return 140 - d.index * (40 + gap)
                })
                .outerRadius(function (d) {
                    return 180 - d.index * (40 + gap)
                })
                .cornerRadius(20);//modified d3 api only

        var background = d3.svg.arc()
                .startAngle(0)
                .endAngle(τ)
                .innerRadius(function (d, i) {
                    return 140 - d.index * (40 + gap)
                })
                .outerRadius(function (d, i) {
                    return 180 - d.index * (40 + gap)
                });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        //add linear gradient, notice apple uses gradient alone the arc..
        //meh, close enough...


        var gradient = svg.append("svg:defs")
                .append("svg:linearGradient")
                .attr("id", "gradient")
                .attr("x1", "0%")
                .attr("y1", "100%")
                .attr("x2", "50%")
                .attr("y2", "0%")
                .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

        gradient.append("svg:stop")
                .attr("offset", "0%")
                .attr("stop-color", "#fe08b5")
                .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

        gradient.append("svg:stop")
                .attr("offset", "100%")
                .attr("stop-color", "#ff1410")
                .attr("stop-opacity", 1);


        //add some shadows
        var defs = svg.append("defs");

        var filter = defs.append("filter")
                .attr("id", "dropshadow")

        filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
                .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
                .attr("stdDeviation", 4)
                .attr("result", "blur");
        filter.append("feOffset")
                .attr("in", "blur")
                .attr("dx", 1)
                .attr("dy", 1)
                .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

        var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

        feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
                .attr("in", "offsetBlur");
        feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
                .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

        var field = svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter().append("g");

        field.append("path").attr("class", "progress").attr("filter", "url(#dropshadow)");

        field.append("path").attr("class", "bg")
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return colors[d.index];
                })
                .style("opacity", 0.2)
                .attr("d", background);

        field.append("text").attr('class','icon');


        if(singleArcView){

            field.append("text").attr('class','goal').text("OF 600 CALS").attr("transform","translate(0,50)");
            field.append("text").attr('class','completed').attr("transform","translate(0,0)");

        }

        d3.transition().duration(1750).each(update);

        function update() {
            field = field
                    .each(function (d) {
                        this._value = d.percentage;
                    })
                    .data(dataset)
                    .each(function (d) {
                        d.previousValue = this._value;
                    });

            field.select("path.progress").transition().duration(1750).delay(function (d, i) {
                return i * 200
            })
                    .ease("elastic")
                    .attrTween("d", arcTween)
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        if(d.index===0){
                            return "url(#gradient)"
                        }
                        return colors[d.index];
                    });

            field.select("text.icon").text(function (d) {
                return d.icon;
            }).attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(10," + -(150 - d.index * (40 + gap)) + ")"

                    });

            field.select("text.completed").text(function (d) {
                return Math.round(d.percentage /100 * 600);
            });

            setTimeout(update, 2000);

        }

        function arcTween(d) {
            var i = d3.interpolateNumber(d.previousValue, d.percentage);
            return function (t) {
                d.percentage = i(t);
                return arc(d);
            };
        }


    }


    build(ranDataset);
    build(ranDataset2,true);


})()
```